# mysql regexp for all column with same data

Tags: mysql, regex

i have a table like this.

```
 id     name    father_name     age
  1     raja     first          12
  2     second   first          13
```

When i execute a below query.

```
SELECT * FROM class WHERE name REGEXP 'first|12'
OR father_name REGEXP 'first|12'
OR age REGEXP 'first|12'
```

I getting below as a results.

```
id  name    father_name     age
1   raja     first          12
2   second   first          13
```

But I want below as a result.

```
id  name    father_name     age
1   raja     first          12
```

If I change name with or condition. I can achieve.But 
As same time the user given raja|12 means

```
SELECT * FROM class WHERE name REGEXP 'raja|12'
    OR father_name REGEXP 'raja|12'
    OR age REGEXP 'raja|12'
```

I want the result like this.

```
id  name    father_name     age
1   raja     first          12
```

Because i dont know which one will get from user name or father_name or age or all the three. So if i get all the three there is no problem. But when i get a singl or doble values so i need to search regarding that.

Is there any possibility to get those results?

Comment: Why are you regex'ing characters for age (which is numeric)? Just use =, <, > or combination thereof for age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `and` instead of `or`, but this is complicated by the fact that you don't seem to care about `name`.  I'm tempted to say:

```
SELECT *
FROM class
WHERE father_name REGEXP 'first|12' AND
      age REGEXP 'first|12';
```

I'm not sure what `name` is doing in the `WHERE` clause.

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you want the best matching row.  If so:

```
SELECT *
FROM class
WHERE name REGEXP 'first|12' OR
      father_name REGEXP 'first|12' OR
      age REGEXP 'first|12'
ORDER BY ((name REGEXP 'first|12') + (father_name REGEXP 'first|12') + (age REGEXP 'first|12')) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer gordon. But i need to search with all the column. Because i dont know which one i get that is may be 'name' or 'father_name' or 'age' or 'all the there' so i want to search like wise. 

I want query based on that.

Comment: when i change AND instead of or, I get empty results.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to search for in all columns.

Comment: Hi Gordon, i got an same results when i removed limit 1.

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that `REGEXP 'xx|yy'` means `this matches xx OR yy` so your result is correct for that query.

To get the result you want, you will have to clarify what you want to achieve. I assume you want the follwing: `select all rows where the father is first AND age is 12`

You can achieve this by using:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE father_name like 'first' AND age = 12;
```

You can try this solution here: [Relevant SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e61bc/5).

**Edit1**: Possible alternative soultion after more comments by OP:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
father_name IN ('first', '12') AND age IN ('first', '12')
OR
father_name IN ('first', '12') AND name IN ('first', '12')
OR
name IN ('first', '12') AND age IN ('first', '12');
```

You can try this solution here: [Relevant SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e61bc/7).

Comment: Hi Igor, The thing is when i get an input from the user. i dont know the order of the inputs string.

For example:
  1) name|fathername|age
  2) fathername|name|age
  3) fathername|age
  4) age|name,

So it should matched with all the field and return matched results.

Comment: So if I enter name|fathername|age and there is only a match on name and fathername, is that a hit or a miss? Also, if I enter name|fathername|age and there is only a hit on name, is that a hit or miss? I am not sure what you want to happen.